# Simplify functions so the code does not get too big

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code so that each element make the scroll effect when done:
I keep repeating the function to each element, the problem that are 30 elements with different classes to add, the code would be very large.

jQuery:

```
  $(window).scroll(function () {
        $('.regalos').each(function () {
            var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;

            var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (imagePos < topOfWindow + 400) {
                $(this).addClass("stretchLeft");
            }
        });

        $('.sprite-Layer-2').each(function () {
            var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;

            var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (imagePos < topOfWindow + 400) {
                $(this).addClass("slideLeft");
            }
        });
       // ... must 28
    });
```

Comment: Do this in a loop. Iterate through an array containing the selectors and class names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();

    function _checkOffset(className) {
        return function () {
            var $this = $(this),
                imagePos = $this.offset().top;

            $this.toggleClass(className, (imagePos < topOfWindow + 400));
        };
    }

    $('.regalos').each(_checkOffset('stretchLeft'));
    $('.sprite-Layer-2').each(_checkOffset('slideLeft'));
});
```

However, you might be better off re-thinking your structure to avoid adding different class names based on the offset.

Comment: exactly how i'd write it. This is pretty much the most concise (but legible) way to write this

Answer (score 0):

You could create a HashMap of Key/Value pairs (key = ID / Class, value = your string inside of .addClass()).  However, this would only work if you only had a single class that you wanted to add via addClass for each key that you had.

Or you could have a complex HashMap, where the value was a an array, that you further iterated through if you really wanted to....

Answer (score 0):

1st, create the function once:

```
var myfunction = function(that, whichway) {
     var imagePos = $(that).offset().top;

     var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
     if (imagePos < topOfWindow + 400) {
       $(that).addClass(whichway); }
     };
```

Then call it as often as you'd like:

```
$('.regalos').each(myfunction(this, 'stretchLeft'));
$('.sprite-layer-2').each(myfunction(this, 'slideLeft'));
```

Answer (score 0):

try the code below:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();

$('.regalos').each(function () {
foo(this, 'stretchLeft');
});

$('.sprite-Layer-2').each(function () {
foo(this, 'slideleft');
});

});

function foo(that, classToBeAdded){
var imagePos = $(that).offset().top;

            if (imagePos < topOfWindow + 400) {
                $(that).addClass(classToBeAdded);
            }
}
```

Comment: @cristanio in the code above the function foo takes care of populating everything and then it adds the class that you specify to add to a selector.

Comment: @cristianomatos what is wrong with my code?? who has downvoted it??

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this, as a global function and you pass array via the items.

```
var fn = function(args) {
     for (var i = 0; i < args.elements.length; i++) {
         var el = args.elements[i];
         $(el).each(function() {
             var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;
             var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
             if (imagePos < topOfWindow + 400) {
                 $(this).addClass(args.cls);
             }
         });
     }

 };
 $(window).scroll(function() {
     fn({
         elements: ['.regalos', '.sprite-layer-2']
         cls: 'stretchLeft'
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a list of classes to the jQuery selector.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    $('.regalos, .sprite-Layer-2').each(function () {
        var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;

        var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (imagePos < topOfWindow + 400) {
            $(this).addClass("stretchLeft");
        }
    });
});
```

But, I would add one class to all the elements and access them by that.

Comment: it seems the new class to be added will be different depending on different selectors.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following, where the key in the rules object is the class to add and the value is the selector for the items to get the class:

```
var rules = {
    "slideLeft": ".sprite-Layer-2",
    "stretchLeft": ".regalos",
    "someOtherClass" : ".abc, .def, .ghi"    // Multiple elements get this class
};

$(window).scroll(function () {

    $.each(rules, function( className, selector) {
        $(selector).each(function () {
            var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;

            var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (imagePos < topOfWindow + 400) {
                $(this).addClass(className);
            }
        });
    });
});
```